# Find JSON value in mongodb java driver 3.0.x

Tags: java, json, mongodb

For instance I am having these two JSON files which I inserted in to mongo DB java driver 3.0.4.
  I am trying to fetch details based on the field Id. But all my efforts are under vain. Can anyone tell where I messed up. Thanks in Advance

```
Document {
    _id = 5721dd81ef31f82754eac196,
    Details = {
        "author_FirstName" : "Nishant",
        "author_LastName" : "Jayanth",
        "book_title" : "skjfsasfhkj",
        "Id" : 78,
        "publisher" : "tata",
        "year" : 1231,
        "ISBN" : 291939
    }

}

Document {
    _id = 5721dd81ef31f82754eac196,
    Details = {
        "author_FirstName" : "Nishant",
        "author_LastName" : "Jayanth",
        "book_title" : "skjfsasfhkj",
        "Id" : 777,
        "publisher" : "tata",
        "year" : 1231,
        "ISBN" : 291939
    }

}
```

This is my code where I am trying to retrieve based on Id.

```
public String getAuthor(String id){
    String pId=String.valueOf(id);
    final String[] author = {null};
    FindIterable<Document> iterable=store.find(new Document("Id", 777)); //Probably this is where something is wrong
    iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
    @Override
    public void apply(final Document document) {
          author[0]=document.toString();
          System.out.println(document);
        }       
    });

        return author[0]; 
    }
```

I tried all the possible combinations to the best of my knowledge.

```
new Document("Document.Details.Id":id);
new Document("Details.Id":id);
new Document("Document.Id":id);
```

But nothing worked.

Comment: Try This:
Document["Details"]["Id"]

Comment: Your JSON documents are strange. Usually for Mongo you should remove the outer "Document" and make it a collection of the same name. The insert documents containing `_id` and `Details`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above JSON doc is not parsed . Parse the document and straight away access with field name.

collection.insertOne(Document.parse(your data));